# Vuejs - How to build external scss with webpack in production

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vue.js, sass

Webpack doesn't build external scss files to css and doesn't include them into app. In development mode everythink is ok, scss files are include and working. Problem is with production build.

I'm using this webpack configuartion: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Folders structure:

```
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── App.vue
├── scss
│   ├── main.scss
│   └── ...
```

I'm import my `scss` in `App.vue`:

`@import './scss/main.scss';`

In `webpack.prod.conf`:

`module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },`

Comment: well just run 'npm run build' and everything should be in './dist' , for me this is working just fine and it includes my styles.scss that i import in main.js

Comment: For me it's not working :/ . How do you import into main.js? Becouse when i'm trying to import scss there, i got error "module not found".

Comment: well i just use _ import './scss/styles.scss' _ directly after _ import router from './router' _ and the scss file is under './src/scss/styles.scss'

Comment: Can you show me your webpack config? Dev and prod env.

Comment: i didnt change anything in them and i used vue-cli to create the project